# MissingMethodException Json.Serializer Constructor on type not found exception in WASM unoplatform

Tags: json, deserialization, .net-standard-2.0, uno-platform

I am using `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize` to deserialize string into my class.

Here is my class:

```cs
namespace Database
{
    public class Song
    {
        public uint id { get; set; }

        public string name { get; set; }

        public string author { get; set; }

        public int bpm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is code of deserialization with jsonData being `[{"id":1,"name":"1","author":"1","bpm":0},{"id":2,"name":"2","author":"2","bpm":0}]`

```
List<Song> songs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Song>>(jsonData);
```

It works perfectly fine on UWP and Android projects in Uno-Platform. However, on WASM exception `MissingMethodException` is thrown. Here is the log:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ListOfTConverter`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Database.Song, BP.Wasm, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Database.Song, BP.Wasm, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.
```

As far I understand the log. It doesn't know how to deserialize `List<Song>`. Neither the [overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview) or any of the *Additional resources* says anything about some exceptions to what types are supported by de/serialization in what framework.

Do I have to define my own converters for `List` of `Song` and potentially other Collections? Could this be related to Uno Platform anyhow? Or am I just missing something trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the linker stripping away the required code. Open the `LinkerConfig.xml` file in the WASM project and try to add your assembly / `System.Text.Json` there:

```
<assembly fullname="System.Text.Json" />
<assembly fullname="Database" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Just note only `<assembly fullname="System.Text.Json" />` was needed. `Database` is my custom assembly which was linked correctly.

Comment: Great, glad it helped :-)